# Altering the DOM manually in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic's `IonPicker` component, which renders, as a *sibling to React's `div#root`*, an `ion-picker` element, which appears to be a full screen overlay, which has two children: an `ion-backdrop` element, and its sibling, `div.picker-wrapper`.

[image]

I am trying to extract just the `div.picker-wrapper` element so that I can, say, place it relative to other components in my app, and I also want to be able to add elements to it, like a button that is a child of `div.picker-wrapper`, and that button would have to be a react component. So I suppose individual access to `div.picker-wrapper`'s existing children, `div.picker-toolbar` and `div.picker-columns`, would be good as well.

And of course I need to be able to use the `IonPicker`'s props and methods and everything.

So I'm trying to grab DOM elements and delete them, move them around, stuff like that, and of course I don't ever want the user to see things disappearing and reappearing, so, there's that.

I imagine the answer involves "Use refs" so please provide more detail. To start, I've tried

```js
  picker: RefObject<HTMLIonPickerElement> = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <IonPicker
        isOpen
        ref={ this.picker }
        animated={ true }
        mode={ 'ios' }
        cssClass={ 'firmm-picker' }
        columns={ this.columns }
        onDidDismiss={ this.props.dismiss }
        buttons={ this.buttons }
        showBackdrop={ false }
      />
    );
  }
```

But `picker` and/or `picker.current` are always undefined or null.

And I've tried `const x = document.getElementById('ion-overlay-1')` in various places (`componentDidMount`, `render`, `shouldComponentUpdate`), and it's never there.

Comment: Have you tried to put it under a componentDidMount() function? It's probably trying to grab the DOM elements before they are loaded.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have tried that. They're still not loaded yet, surprisingly. It could be possibly because of some entrance animation, but I set `animated={false}` with no improvement.